# Create a dynamic parameter to update the graph when a user zooms in. (tableau)

Tags: time-series, tableau-api

I have a time series graph that loads the initial values using the start date and end date parameters to the right, as seen in the picture below. I need to set it up to update the date range to whatever date range the user zooms into.

Any suggestions on how to setup a dynamic parameter for date ?

For reference, the updated date will hit a database function in Postgres which will return more granular data for smaller date ranges instead of down sampling for a large range.

[image]

Clarification based on comments:

1. the report loads up and the graph is blank
2. user selects start date and end date in the parameters, the data for this range is loaded from the DB
3. the graph loads up and the user can zoom and pan in the graph
4. when the user zooms in, the date range in the graph updates. in the picture... the date range is from Aug 2020 to March 2021, but the user is zoomed into Jan.

Asking for: when zoomed in like in step 4, I want to update the Date Start and Date End with the zoomed in Values, so in this case, 12th Aug 2020 should become 1 Jan 2021 and end date should become 2 Jan 2021

Comment: Do you mean to say you have actually made two parameters as visible in pic, but you need the directions to set them in action?

Comment: Actually your question is not clear. When you have made 2 parameters to set 2 dates what else do you want?

Comment: I just added the steps for clarification. Thank you

Comment: you mean parameters should change as per zoom?? IMHO if that could be the case what's the need of parameters?

Comment: the use case would be to change the date to any arbitrary date after zooming in. or any other UX details. do you think that what I am trying to do is not possible ?

Comment: It seems so.  Because zoom& pan are normally browser dependent

Answer (score 1):

Please check this one,

[1-Date Granularity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hHZWZSsP98)

Good luck.